# Blender 2.8 Object and Background plane disappear

Tags: camera

Using Blender 2.8 with the Eevee render engine.  From the camera perspective with Lock Camera to View, when I zoom out the objects start to disappear.  Here are 3 images of the project, the further I zoom out the more the objects are cut off.
I did not changed the camera perspective only using the middle mouse button to zoom (scroll) out.  What needs to be changed to eliminate this problem?

[image: Zoom Level 1]

[image: Zoom Level 2]

[image: Zoom Level 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is your camera clipping, it will only show object in a certain distance of the camera. You need to make it where it will show objects further away. in your screen shot, in the menu to the right you will see the clipping settings. Set the clipping end at 1500 or so and you should see everything.

Okay try going to object mode and opening the N bar on the right. fin the view tab and click it. That will open the scene clipping. you can try upping the end clipping on it, and see if that helps.

Select the camera object, then to the right where the where all the the icons are select the green camera and you will find the camera clipping. Up the end value there.

Comment: Jarrett, I tried your fix it did not work.  I still cannot scroll out no matter how large the setting is on clip end

Comment: I added something to try.

Comment: Thanks that was actually the place I was adjusting the first time. I must have missed something in the main property panel

Comment: Okay I found where to edit the camera clipping. I added it above.

Comment: Yep, that was the exact spot.  Missed that the first time.

Comment: My fault, I should have told you better where. I hope it fixed the problem.